# React mobx does not inject stores properly

Tags: mobx-react

I have implemented this but the store has no values (all undefined):

This is the store:

```
export default class AppState {

    // Is authenticated
    @observable authenticated;

    @action get authenticated() {
        return this.authenticated;
    }

    doSomethingWithNoDecorator() {
      return this.authenticated;
    }
 }
```

This is index.js:

```
const stores = {
    AppState
};

const renderApp = Component => {
    render(
        <AppContainer>

            <Provider { ...stores }>
                <Router>
                    // Routes
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById("root")
    );
};
```

This is the Component:

```
@inject("AppState")
@observer
export default class SidebarListItem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.store = this.props.AppState;
    }

    doSomething() {
        this.store.authenticated();
        this.store.doSomethingWithNoDecorator();
        this.store.authenticated;        
    }
}
```

The store is not null... I can see the function. But I can't get any field or invoke any method.

What did I do wrong?

Regards,
Idob

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise your store:

```
const stores = { AppState: new AppState() }
```

By the way, @actions cannot be applied to getters.